# Cannot add view dynamically to Linear Layout within a Frame Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add two TextViews programmatically within a linear layout that resides in a frame layout. The xml code is:

```
<FrameLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
               <LinearLayout
                   android:id="@+id/ll_dynamic"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                   android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                   android:orientation="vertical" >

               </LinearLayout>

               <com.anheuserbusch.hifive.util.TextViewFiftySeven
                   android:id="@+id/txt_no_badges"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:visibility="gone"
                   android:textColor="@color/app_default_font_color"
                   android:text="@string/no_badges_yet"/>

           </FrameLayout>
```

**ll_dynamic** is the Linear Layout in which I am adding the views programatically.

**The code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                TextViewFiftySeven txtIncentiveName = new TextViewFiftySeven(context);
                TextViewFiftySeven txtDate = new TextViewFiftySeven(context);


                //for Incentive name
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llptextname = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                llptextname.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

                //for date
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llptextdate = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                llptextdate.setMargins(0, 1, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

                txtIncentiveName.setLayoutParams(llptextname);
                txtIncentiveName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.app_default_font_color));
                txtIncentiveName.setText("Summer Incentive");

                txtDate.setLayoutParams(llptextdate);
                txtDate.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.app_default_font_color));
                txtDate.setText("23.2.2015");

                holder.ll_dynamic.addView(txtIncentiveName);
                holder.ll_dynamic.addView(txtDate);
                System.out.println("Looping-->"+i);


                if (i != badgeCount - 1) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llhorizontalLine = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2);
                    llhorizontalLine.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
                    View horizontalLine = new View(context);
                    horizontalLine.setLayoutParams(llhorizontalLine);
                    horizontalLine.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray_light));
                    holder.ll_dynamic.addView(horizontalLine);
                }
            }
```

The problem is,the views are not getting added programatically. But if I **remove the frame layout then the views are rendered as desired**. Clearly it is a problem due to the frame layout. But I need to keep the frame layout.

**So why are the views not added dynamically to the linear layout if it is within the frame layout?**

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation of the FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) it is meant to be used with just one child layout.

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

You can however control the child views using `layout-gravity`

> You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

So in your case you could add a `layout-gravity` attribute in the layout xml under `TextViewFiftySeven` and every time you add a view programmatically.

Comment: I am adding view inside the linear layout that resides within the frame layout...not to the frame layout itself

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Still the layout-gravity might work. Or try removing the TextViewFiftySeven from the xml and check if the LinearLayout works as intended. If not, are you sure you have to use a FrameLayout? There are many other layouts available that might give you your desired results.

Comment: Yes I have accomplished my task by removing the frame layout...but logically I could not able to find any mistake while adding to linear layout THAT RESIDES WITHIN FRAME LAYOUT.But dont know why it is not happenning.